# Price dispersion in online retail Of BookTown.in

Tags: books

Since these are homogenous goods and anyone who can access one of the stores can as easily assess another I wonder how we might explain this price dispersion. I have not done a systematic study but it is my impression that it is not the case that there is an ordering of prices between stores which is the same for different books.

https://www.booktown.in/

Comment: "*anyone who can access one of the stores can as easily assess another I wonder how we might explain this price dispersion*" How you considered that not everyone is savvy or wants to spend time searching for the lower price? There is academic literature in IO on 'search costs'.